# Is Intellisense wrong or am I?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I've got what I think is an Intellisense bug that I should report but I want to be sure.

I'm writing a multi-binding with a Converter for the IsHitTestVisible property of a grid.  When my grid's opacity fades down to zero, I set `IsHitTestVisible` to false. (The fading happens elsewhere in an animation).

Here's the relevant XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="DetailGrid" >

    <Grid.IsHitTestVisible>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{net:CompareConverter}" ConverterParameter="{x:Static net:CompareOp.Greater}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" 
                     Path="Opacity" />    <!-- INTELLISENSE DOESNT LIKE THIS -->
            <Binding Source="{net:DoubleVal 0.0}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Grid.IsHitTestVisible>
</Grid>
```

Intellisense tells me that "Opacity" is not a property of MultiBinding.  And that's true.  But `RelativeSource Self` should refer to the Grid, not the MultiBinding, right?

I'm not looking for a workaround.  I'm trying to understand if Intellisense is mistaken.  Because it seems to be;  The binding seems to work.  I just want to be sure.  (Besides, I already have a workaround:  If I switch from RelativeSource Self to `ElementName="DetailGrid"` there is no Intellisense error)

So am I correct that Intellisense has got this wrong?

**[EDIT].**  Since my example uses a converter and things that others don't have.  Here's a much simpler example to demonstrate the issue.

Given this simple, dummy multi-converter that just returns the first value it is given (or 0)

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TestBindingWarning
{
public class ReturnFirstConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] vals, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c) => 
        vals.Length > 0 ? vals[0] : 0;

    public object[] ConvertBack(object v, Type[] tt, object p, CultureInfo c) =>
        Enumerable.Repeat(Binding.DoNothing, tt.Length).ToArray();
}
}
```

Imagine a grid that tried to bind its width to its height with a multibinding.  Nonsensical, yes, but legal and the app runs

```
<Grid Height="100" Background="Blue">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ReturnFirstConverter x:Key="Cvt"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.Width>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Cvt}" >
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Height"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Grid.Width>
</Grid>
```

In this case, Intellisense, will complain that "The property 'Height' is not found in "MultiBinding".  This is the issue

Comment: You're right, Intellisense is wrong. It happens! And generally you want to use `RelativeSource` as much as possible, because it won't break if you put it in user controls or virtualized/generated panels (like `ItemsControl`).

Comment: It would only be "a bug" if Intellisense would be supposed to resolve *everything*. Pretty certainly you won't find such a requirement. I'd refrain from reporting.

Comment: I won't find any requirements.  There is no published requirements doc.  But when a tool indicates a problem that does not exist, it's a bug.

Comment: Please try to close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder, then restart project, did the error happen again?

Comment: Or you could try to create a new project to test whether this error happens agian.

Comment: Per your answer I've actually tried those things.  Still occurs.  Simplified my example above so that anyone can make this happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I switch from RelativeSource Self to ElementName="DetailGrid" there
> is no Intellisense error) So am I correct that Intellisense has got
> this wrong?

**Since** I did not have your full sample to test it. I suggest you could try these steps to troubleshoot your issue to check whether it is an issue of VS or your project itself:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions** menu to check if an extension causes this behavior.

**2)** delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin`and `obj` folder and then restart your project to test again.

**3)** please try to create a new empty wpf project(disable any third party extensions), if you did not face the same issue in the new project, it is related to your specific project itself. And follow the above two steps. Or just migrating your old project into the new project might be a good choice.

If you face the same issue on the new project, then it should be an issue of VS.

**Before it**, you should [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update VS to the latest version in case some fixes are already released.

======================================================

If you try all the steps and still get the same error, please feel free to let us know and we will help you report this issue to give you a better support.

**Update 1**

Quite a strange intellisense behavior and I already [report this issue on our DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1088811/intellisense-error-with-multibinding-and-returns-t.html). You can check the link and vote it or add any comment if I did not describe the issue in detailed.

Anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  However I've actually tried all of these things aside from the repair of VS.  There is no problem with VS install.  This is something easily reproducible.  All you need is a MultiBinding with an internal Binding that tries to use the datacontext of the same FrameworkElement.  In my example above, if you were to take out the whole "Converter" part of the MultiBinding and just have the first single Binding inside of it you would see the issue.  I see it now on multiple MultiBindings on more than one PC

Comment: Ha.  Thank you.  Actually after the first guy said it was a bug I also reported it.  I guess I should have mentioned that.  I just wasn't expecting you to report it

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1084337/intellisense-gets-relativesource-self-wrong-within.html

Comment: Okay. I will vote your link and hope the team will give you a satisfactory reply.

Comment: Since it is an intellisense issue and we both report it to the team and share the links here, `I think you could consider accepting the answer`.  It is kind of you to do that. Also, I will follow the link and track this issue and provide you with more likely help. Thanks:)

Comment: OK, I'll accept the answer but in fairness, the guy @Blindy who posted the first comment really had it right.  If he'd posted that as the answer I would have accepted it.  Regardless I appreciate both your time.